# Azure Consumption REST APIs usageStart not working

Tags: rest, azure, azure-sdk-.net

I am querying Azure Consumption REST API using postman. properties/usageEnd (Utc time), properties/usageStart (Utc time) filter is not working

Tried below options:

> https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?api-version=2019-01-01&filter=properties/usageStart eq \'2019-02-01T00:00:00Z\' and  properties/usageEnd eq \'2019-02-14T00:00:00Z\'
>
> usageStart eq '2018-04-01' AND usageEnd eq '2018-05-30'
>
> properties/usageStart eq '2019-02-01T00:00:00Z' and properties/usageEnd eq '2019-02-14T00:00:00Z'
>
> usageStart eq 17/10/2018 15:18:06 and usageEnd eq 17/10/2018 16:18:06

I am actually for date filter for this API and it is not working.

Comment: It seems to "work" when you request very recent information, like the usage from the past week or so. When I go further in the past, I get very random results.

Comment: Hi Nithin, try using &$filter instead of &filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works perfectly for me.

```
https://management.azure.azure.com/subscriptions/{SubscriptionGuid}/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?api-version=2019-01-01&$filter=properties/usageEnd+ge+'2019-02-12'+AND+properties/usageEnd+le+'2019-02-14'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding milliseconds precision to your dates. For example, try the following:

```
properties/usageStart eq '2019-02-01T00:00:00.0000000Z' and properties/usageEnd eq '2019-02-14T00:00:00.0000000Z'
```

Comment: I have the same issue, the results I get are very random. If I ask the usage from 2018-01-01 to 2018-01-07 I might get results from 2018-02-05...